# Is there in WinAPI, POSIX, or in other extensions of API-OS equivalents to all levels of memory barriers from C++11?

Tags: c++, winapi, c++11, posix, memory-barriers

Is there in WinAPI, POSIX, or in other extensions of API-OS equivalents to **all levels of memory barriers** from C++11 [std::memory_order](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/memory_order), which define the limits on the optimization when reordering operations by the compiler and processor pipeline?

```
enum memory_order {
    memory_order_relaxed,
    memory_order_consume,
    memory_order_acquire,
    memory_order_release,
    memory_order_acq_rel,
    memory_order_seq_cst
};
```

**ADDITION:** An example in WinAPI is present [MemoryBarrier()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/ms684208%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), but it is only equivalents to `std::atomic_thread_fence( std::memory_order_seq_cst );`. Because Windows mostly works on x86-systems, where plain loads have acquire semantics and plain stores have release semantics: http://www.stdthread.co.uk/forum/index.php?topic=72.0

But, even if the cache L3 (LLC) and the pipeline of x86 cancels reordering optimizations for the `load()` and `store()` in accordance with these semantics - `std::memory_order_acquire/std::memory_order_release` need also to disable compiler optimizations.

It is present in **[WinAPI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f20w0x5e%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)**:

> The **_ReadBarrier, _WriteBarrier, and _ReadWriteBarrier** compiler
> intrinsics prevent only compiler re-ordering. To prevent the CPU from
> re-ordering read and write operations, use the MemoryBarrier macro.

There are in [**GCC built-in** functions for memory model aware atomic operations](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/_005f_005fatomic-Builtins.html):

> __ATOMIC_RELAXED No barriers or synchronization.
>
> __ATOMIC_CONSUME Data dependency only for both barrier and synchronization with another thread.
>
> __ATOMIC_ACQUIRE Barrier to hoisting of code and synchronizes with release (or stronger) semantic stores from another thread.
>
> __ATOMIC_RELEASE Barrier to sinking of code and synchronizes with acquire (or stronger) semantic loads from another thread.
>
> __ATOMIC_ACQ_REL Full barrier in both directions and synchronizes with acquire loads and release stores in another thread.
>
> __ATOMIC_SEQ_CST Full barrier in both directions and synchronizes with acquire loads and release stores in all threads.

And can I disable this compiler optimizations by using **POSIX**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally not part of the API standards, but available as intrinsics in most compilers in one form or another.

For example, Visual Studio compilers have [`_ReadBarrier`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f20w0x5e%28v=vs.90%29.aspx), `_ReadWriteBarrier` and `_WriteBarrier`. (I only linked one, as there are links from that page to the rest. And no, these are not all the levels you have listed - but they are all the levels that x86 has... The list in `std::memory_order` covers a bunch of other architectures too. [And obvioously `memory_order_relaxed` is "nothing"].

GCC has a different type of builtin functionality described [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/_005f_005fatomic-Builtins.html), which is aimed at supplying atomic updates, rather than specifically barriers.

However, in general, I would leave it to the compiler/OS to deal with atomic things - use `std::atomic<>` and similar.

Answer (score 0):

Almost certainly not.  The goal of the standard was to cover all
eventualities; you specify the minimum that you need, and the
compiler provides the minimum in its environment which meets the
requirements.

As for compiler optimizations: I suppose that a compiler could
evaluate these arguments to the atomic functions, and make
optimization dependent on it, but I rather suspect that most
compilers will use a much simpler rule: no reordering of memory
accesses (at the compiler level) accross accesses to an atomic
type.

And I'm not sure what compiler optimizations you want to
disable.  If the compiler is Posix compliant, it will disable
all reordering of memory accesses accross any of the
`pthread_...` functions; and probably accross all system
functions.  (Imagine if it reordered a write to the buffer 
after the call to `write`, or a read from a buffer before the
call to `read`.)